# htaccess mod rewrite for phpmyadmin

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, phpmyadmin

I have been searching with no success on getting my mod rewrite rule to work. I am creating a site like most now that use a rewrite rule to point back to a specific php file that will display content based on the url.  The issue i am having, is trying to get the rewrite rule NOT to apply if the user went to "something.com/phpmyadmin"  I know it has been asked before, and i have read those posts, but i still cant seem to get mine to work, here is the rewrite scripts i have, and it is still sending me to the /index.php instead of /phpmyadmin/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/phpmyadmin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

If i go to /phpmyadmin/index.php it works fine, but i am really bothered why i cant get the directory part to work.

Comment: The only other note, is that the /phpmyadmin/ is an alias as the deafult install as PhpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

You should use `THE_REQUEST` variable:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/phpmyadmin [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

Comment: This is giving me the exact same result.  it is a clean apache install with very little changes to the default config file, just simply using a virtual host.  Shouldnt rewrite cond be "AND" by default, i am not sure what is causing it to evaluate as true..

Comment: See updated rule and make sure this is the only code in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`. Also is there any .htaccess in `/phpmyadmin/`?

Comment: This is the only code in the htaccess. and the phpmyadmin is not using any .htaccess.

Comment: I have `phpmyadmin` installed and this rule does work well by stopping `/phpmyadmin` being rewritten to `/index.php`.